# How to sort file sizes in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables plugin to show the records from my database. In my database I have this table named `size` and it contains varchar datatype that stores file sizes so here are samples of what I have

[image]

When displayed in my tables I have this button that is supposed to sort the file sizes into asc or desc order but it does not sort the records properly say for example this one

[image]

my code right now to sort the filesize looks like this

```
$("#sortfilesize").click(function() {

    if(checkb ==0){
       oTable.order( [ 5, 'asc' ] );
       checkb = 1;
    }else{
       oTable.order( [ 5, 'desc' ] );
       checkb = 0;
    }
    oTable.draw(); 
});
```

**update**

i have downloaded file-size.js then when initializing my detail table it looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#detailTable').DataTable({
                        bPaginate: false,
                        "columnDefs": [{ "type": "file-size", "targets": 5 }],
                        "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [1,6,7,8,9,10,11] }],
                        "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],

                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a DataTables sorting plug-in for that - [File size](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/file-size). From the manual:

> When dealing with computer file sizes, it is common to append a post
>   fix such as B, KB, MB or GB to a string in order to easily denote the
>   order of magnitude of the file size. This plug-in allows sorting to
>   take these indicates of size into account.

In addition to jQuery and DataTables library you need to include the latest plug-in script (see plug-in page for the up-to-date link).

Sample initialization code is shown below:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { "type": "file-size", "targets": 1 }
    ]    
});
```

Property `targets` indicates zero-based column index that contains file sizes.

See example below for demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
     "columnDefs": [
       { "type": "file-size", "targets": 1 }
     ]    
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/sorting/file-size.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Small.mp3</td>
      <td>9 KB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Normal.mp3</td>
      <td>8 MB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Large.mp3</td>
      <td>7 GB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smallest.mp3</td>
      <td>10 B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi would this work of i have decimal point in my file size? thanks

Comment: here is how i initialize my detailTable but it is not working. any idea? `<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#detailTable').DataTable({
                bPaginate: false,
                "columnDefs": [{ "type": "file-size", "targets": 5 }],
                "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [1,6,7,8,9,10,11] }],
                "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                
               });
           });
       </script>`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution which works for KB and MB. You could account for GB with another elseif conditional. This works for data like this:

```
128   <- bytes
16KB  <- 16 Kilobytes
1.4MB <- 1.4 Megabytes
```

Use my code in case you don't want to mess with the plugin or can't get it working.

```
    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['file-size-asc'] = function (a, b) {
        if (a.includes('KB')) {
            a = parseFloat(a.replace('KB','')) *1024;
        } else
        if (a.includes('MB')) {
            a = parseFloat(a.replace('MB','')) *1024*1024;
        }
    
        if (b.includes('KB')) {
            b = parseFloat(b.replace('KB','')) *1024;
        } else
        if (b.includes('MB')) {
            b = parseFloat(b.replace('MB','')) *1024*1024;
        }
        return (( a > b ) ? 1 : -1);
    };
    
    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['file-size-desc'] = function (a, b) {
        if (a.includes('KB')) {
            a = parseFloat(a.replace('KB','')) *1024;
        } else
        if (a.includes('MB')) {
            a = parseFloat(a.replace('MB','')) *1024*1024;
        }
    
        if (b.includes('KB')) {
            b = parseFloat(b.replace('KB','')) *1024;
        } else
        if (b.includes('MB')) {
            b = parseFloat(b.replace('MB','')) *1024*1024;
        }
        return (( a > b ) ? -1 : 1);
    };
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#my_data_table").dataTable( {
            "pageLength": 25,
            "aoColumns": [{"sType": "file-size"}],
            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        } );
    });
```

Comment: Great example without having to use the plugin.